# How to display IP address of eth0 interface using a shell script?

Tags: scripts, ip, interface

How can I display the IP address shown on eth0 using a script ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For the sake of providing another option, you could use the `ip addr` command this way to get the IP address:

```
ip addr show eth0 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1
```

- `ip addr show eth0` shows information about `eth0`
- `grep "inet\b"` only shows the line that has the IPv4 address (if you wanted the IPv6 address, change it to `"inet6\b"`)
- `awk '{print $2}'` prints on the second field, which has the ipaddress/mask, example `172.20.20.15/25`
- `cut -d/ -f1` only takes the IP address portion.

In a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
theIPaddress=$(ip addr show eth0 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1)
```

Comment: this solution actually works!

Comment: ip -4 ... and ip -6 ...! Thank you!

Comment: `ip addr show eth0 | grep -P "inet6?\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1` will print both IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score 31):

Note: This answer is for older systems. If this does not work for you please consider other answers. This answer is not incorrect.

save this in a file and then run `bash <filename>`

```
#!/bin/bash
ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr"
```

being more accurate to get only number showing IP address:

```
#!/bin/bash
ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr" | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

**Update**: If this doesn't works for you, try the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/560466/294611)

**Update**: For Ubuntu 18+, try: (don't forget to replace `eth0` with interface you need the IP for. Thanks to @ignacio )

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: of course this doesn't work in the latest ubuntu.  the latest ifconfig returns "inet <ip>" instead of "inet addr <ip>"

Comment: you can just use `grep "inet"`

Comment: here is an updated solution for ifconfig version "net-tools 2.10-alpha" :

ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet" | grep -v "inet6" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' | cut -d ' ' -f 2

Comment: @MaximeAncelin you should add new answer for this

Comment: quick update for `Ubuntu 18.04`: `ifconfig wlan0 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 30):

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14910952/1695680

```
hostname -i
```

However that may return a local ip address (127.0.0.1), so you may have to use, and filter:

```
hostname -I
```

From hostname's manpages:

> `-i, --ip-address`
>
> Display the network address(es) of the host name. Note that this works only if the  host  name  can  be  resolved. Avoid using this option; use hostname --all-ip-addresses instead.
>
> `-I, --all-ip-addresses`
>
> Display  all  network addresses of the host. This option enumerates all configured addresses on all network inter‐faces. The loopback interface and IPv6 link-local addresses are omitted. Contrary to option -i, this  option  does not depend on name resolution. Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output.

Comment: for the record, I like `ip addr show label 'enp*'` better, but I is annoying parse, something like `ip addr show label 'enp*' | grep -oP inet\ \\S+ | cut -d' ' -f2` can work... how pretty

Comment: `ip route | grep default | grep -oP 'dev \S+' | cut -d' ' -f 2 | xargs ip addr show dev | grep -oP 'inet6? \S+'`

Answer (score 10):

You should use `ip` (instead of `ifconfig`) as it's current, maintained, and perhaps most importantly for scripting purposes, it produces a consistent & parsable output. Following are a few similar approaches:

If you want the IPv4 address for your Ethernet interface `eth0`:

```
$ ip -4 -o addr show eth0 | awk '{print $4}'
192.168.1.166/24
```

As a script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash  
INTFC=eth0  
MYIPV4=$(ip -4 -o addr show $INTFC | awk '{print $4}') 
echo $MYIPV4
```

will yield: `192.168.1.166/24` as its output

The output produced above is in [CIDR notation.](https://whatismyipaddress.com/cidr) If CIDR notation isn't wanted, it can be stripped:

```bash
$ ip -4 -o addr show eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d "/" -f 1 
192.168.1.166
```

Another option that IMHO is "most elegant" gets the IPv4 address for whatever interface is used to connect to the specified remote host (8.8.8.8 in this case). Courtesy of @gatoatigrado in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474172/how-to-find-network-interface-name):

```bash
$ ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{ print $NF; exit }'
192.168.1.166
```

Or, as a script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash  
RHOST=8.8.8.8  
MYIP=$(ip route get $RHOST | awk '{ print $NF; exit }')
echo $MYIP
```

will yield: `192.168.1.166` as its output

This works perfectly well on a host with a single interface, but more advantageously will also work on hosts with multiple interfaces and/or route specifications.

While `ip` would be my preferred approach, it's certainly not the only way to skin this cat. Here's another approach that uses `hostname` if you prefer something easier/more concise:

```
$ hostname --all-ip-addresses | awk '{print $1}'
```

Or, if you want the IPv6 address:

```
$ hostname --all-ip-addresses | awk '{print $2}'
```

As a script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MYV4IP=$(hostname --all-ip-addresses | awk '{print $1}') 
MYV6IP=$(hostname --all-ip-addresses | awk '{print $2}')
echo $MYV4IP
echo $MYV6IP
```

will yield: `192.168.1.166`, and `2601:7c1:103:b27:352e:e151:c7d8:3379` as its answers (*assuming you have an IPv6 address assigned*).

Answer (score 8):

@markus-lindberg 's response is my favourite. If you add `-o -4` to ip's flags then you get a much more easily parsable (and consistent) output:

```
ip -o -4 a | awk '$2 == "eth0" { gsub(/\/.*/, "", $4); print $4 }'
```

`-o` stands for `--oneline`, which is meant to help in exactly this kind of situations. The `-4` is added to limit to the IPv4 address, which is what all the other responses imply.

Comment: Love the `ip` flags. Using `cut` rather than advanced `awk` wizardry: ```ip -o -4 addr show eth0 scope global | awk '{print $4;}' | cut -d/ -f 1```

Comment: @DuffJ it's probably down to a matter of personal taste. I "discovered" `cut` way after I learned about `awk`, and I like minimising the number of commands on my pipelines. Nice suggestion in any case.

Comment: I completely agree, Amos. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: Very helpful. This should be the accepted answer, and this is not using the deprecated `ifconfig` which needs you to explicitly install `net-tools` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some oneliners.....

**Awk**

```
ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/{split($2,a,":"); print a[2]}'
```

split function in the above awk command splits the second column based on the delimiter `:` and stores the splitted value into an associative array `a`. So `a[2]` holds the value of the second part.

**sed**

```
ifconfig eth0 | sed -n '/inet addr/s/.*inet addr: *\([^[:space:]]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

In basic sed , `\(...\)` called capturing group which is used to capture the characters. We could refer those captured characters through back-referencing. `\([^[:space:]]\+\)` captures any character but not space one or more times.

**grep**

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -oP 'inet addr:\K\S+'
```

`\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final and `\S+` matches one or more non-space characters.

**Perl**

```
ifconfig eth0 | perl -lane 'print $1 if /inet addr:(\S+)/'
```

One or more non-space characters which are next to the `inet addr:` string are captured and finally we print those captured characters only.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds added some explanation. I think this would be helpful for future readers. Feel free to ask any questions from the above commands... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ip addr|awk '/eth0/ && /inet/ {gsub(/\/[0-9][0-9]/,""); print $2}'
```

This only use `ip addr` which is a replacement for `ifconfig` and `awk` combined with substitution (gsub).

[Stop using too many processes for simple tasks](http://lindberg.io/2015/06/10/stop-using-too-many-processes-for-simple-tasks/)

Answer (score 2):

Just one more option that can be useful if you don't have awk (as it is the case in some embedded devices):

```
ip addr show dev eth0 scope global | grep "inet\b" | cut -d/ -f 1 | egrep -o "([[:digit:]]{1,3}[.]{1}){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good one, only uses grep as secondary command:

ip addr show eth0 | grep -oP 'inet \K\S[0-9.]+'

I don't see why you should use more commands than needed

Answer (score 2):

`ifconfig eth0|grep 'inet '|awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 2):

here's for **IPv4**:

`ip -f inet a|grep -oP "(?<=inet ).+(?=\/)"`

here's for **IPv4** & particular **dev** (eth0):

`ip -f inet a show eth0|grep -oP "(?<=inet ).+(?=\/)"`

for **IPv6**:

`ip -6 -o a|grep -oP "(?<=inet6 ).+(?=\/)"`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a python library like [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) that is specifically designed for this purpose.

```
sudo pip install netifaces
python -c "import netifaces; print netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr']"
```

To obtain the default network interface that is in use.

```
default_inf = netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be used with a normal user too.

```
ip addr show eth0 | grep "inet " | cut -d '/' -f1 | cut -d ' ' -f6
```

Comment: he ask for eth0,  this version of your script could help (also show loopback tho) `ip addr show | grep "inet " | cut -d '/' -f1 | cut -d ' ' -f6`

Comment: This is pretty much the same answer as https://askubuntu.com/a/560466/367990, just using `cut` twice instead of a combination of `awk` and `cut` to parse the output. Next time you should better check out all other answers first and ensure you don't post a duplicate solution. In this case here, I think it's arguable whether it's a duplicate or just similar, so please take it as a general hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in these days with multiples interfaces (eg if you use a docker) and naming interface by ETH is not anymore the norms

I use this command to extract the IP/Mask :

```
IPMASK=$(ip a s|grep -A8 -m1 MULTICAST|grep -m1 inet|cut -d' ' -f6)
```

So whatever how many interfaces I'll have and whatever their name, GREP will only grab the first having the MULTICAST option.

I use this command to extract only the IP without the mask :

```
IP=$(ip a s|grep -A8 -m1 MULTICAST|grep -m1 inet|cut -d' ' -f6|cut -d'/' -f1)
```

I use these command on different BDS & NIX it never fail ;)

Comment: If you're going to parse the output of `ip`, use the `-o` option.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way (assuming you don't want a `CIDR` address and want `IPv4`):

```
$ ip -br -4 addr show dev eth0 | awk '{split($3,a,"/"); print a[1]}'
```

- Uses the `ip` command which is not `deprecated`
- Uses only one command for filtering

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way I could find:

`ip -f inet addr show $1 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'`

Replace `$1` with your network interface.

`ip -f inet` tells ip to only return values for the inet (ipv4) family.

`grep -Po` tells grep to interperate the next value as a perl-regex, and only print the matching values.

The regex `\K[\d.]+` says "throw away everything up to this point (\K), and match as many numeric values followed by a dot in a row as possible". This will therefore only match the IP address and ignore everything after it, including the shortform \XX subnet mask.

Answer (score 0):

In my script I'm using something like that:

```sh
re="inet[[:space:]]+([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"
if [[ $(ip addr show eth0) =~ $re ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
    echo "Cannot determin IP" 1>&2
fi
```

It doesn't spawn any process.

Answer (score 0):

If eth0 has multiple IPs and you are looking for a public one here is an example of ignoring the 2 most common internal IP address ranges.

```bsh
ip -4 addr show eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}' | grep --invert-match -P '^(10\.|192\.168\.)'
```

This ignores 10.0.0.0/8 and 192.168.0.0/16 IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like the other entries suggest,
but you can also do it like a bauss:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# IPs Table

type column &>/dev/null || apt-get install -yq bsdextrautils

links() { ip link | awk '/^[0-9]+:/ { sub(":", "", $2); sub("@.*", "", $2 ); print $2; }'; }
ipof()  { ip addr show ${1:-enp6s0} | awk ' /link.ether/ { print "mac", $2 }
                                           /inet6*/ { print $1, $2 }'; }
( echo dev inet inet6 mac
for i in `links`; do
    unset ips a b c d
    ips=$(ipof $i)
    if [[ -z $ips ]]; then
        mac=.
        inet=.
        inet6=.
    else
        read -s -r -d ';' _ mac _ inet _ inet6 <<< "$ips;"
        if [[ -z $inet6 ]] && [[ $inet =~ :: ]]; then
            inet6=$inet
            inet=
        fi
    fi
    echo $i ${inet:--} ${inet6:--} ${mac:--}
done; ) | column -t
```

The [script is from my collection](https://github.com/tox2ik/local-bin/blob/master/ipt)

Sample output A:

```
dev       inet              inet6                         mac
lo        127.0.0.1/8       ::1/128                       00:00:00:00:00:00
enp6s0    192.168.0.4/24    fe80::aaa1:59ff:fe50:85ea/64  a8:a1:59:50:85:ea
enp4s0d1  -                 -                             24:8a:07:6b:5d:52
ibp4s0    -                 -                             80:00:02:20:fe:80:00:00:00:00:00:00:24:8a:07:03:00:6b:5d:51
virbr0    192.168.122.1/24  -                             52:54:00:f3:77:52
virbr1    192.168.39.1/24   -                             52:54:00:cf:77:c6
vboxnet0  -                 -                             0a:00:27:00:00:00
vboxnet1  -                 -                             0a:00:27:00:00:01
vboxnet2  -                 -                             0a:00:27:00:00:02
vboxnet3  -                 -                             0a:00:27:00:00:03
vboxnet4  -                 -                             0a:00:27:00:00:04
```

Sample output B:

```
dev              inet             inet6                         mac
lo               127.0.0.1/8      ::1/128                       00:00:00:00:00:00
ens3             10.40.237.34/18  fe80::8de:f6ff:fe19:f315/64   0a:de:f6:19:f3:15
lxcbr0           172.16.0.1/16    fe80::216:3eff:fe00:0/64      00:16:3e:00:00:00
vaf.sta.RsuBSCQ  -                fe80::fc91:4fff:fed1:6adc/64  fe:91:4f:d1:6a:dc
vaf.cra.G4EHHKb  -                fe80::fc47:69ff:fe86:abc6/64  fe:47:69:86:ab:c6
vaf.com.t2VC1vD  -                fe80::fc25:cff:fec5:515b/64   fe:25:0c:c5:51:5b
vaf.lor.cXYkGKF  -                fe80::fce8:6dff:fed1:8d08/64  fe:e8:6d:d1:8d:08
vaf.iff.2I4P4ay  -                fe80::fca0:6dff:fe33:e198/64  fe:a0:6d:33:e1:98
vaf.bag.etDqGZ3  -                fe80::fca6:c9ff:fe17:8e4f/64  fe:a6:c9:17:8e:4f
vaf.bor.L9tqMch  -                fe80::fc90:92ff:fe48:bf48/64  fe:90:92:48:bf:48
vaf.dan.GhojJo8  -                fe80::fc0c:71ff:feaa:8b81/64  fe:0c:71:aa:8b:81
vaf.tru.ZuH5xfb  -                fe80::fc2e:21ff:fe91:2ce5/64  fe:2e:21:91:2c:e5
vaf.huo.6ii1Tyy  -                fe80::fcbe:fbff:fe59:44f5/64  fe:be:fb:59:44:f5
vaf.nwt.CFoTS9J  -                fe80::fc5d:3fff:feac:917f/64  fe:5d:3f:ac:91:7f
vethe8qi4n       -                fe80::fca2:10ff:feec:5e2b/64  fe:a2:10:ec:5e:2b
vaf.cra.6gHyk8E  -                fe80::fc23:4bff:fe2c:e9b/64   fe:23:4b:2c:0e:9b
```